# Is "A scales with B in the same way as C" ambiguous?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

In the sentence "A scales with B in the same way as C," A, B and C represent some scientific terms. I wrote it with a 'does' at the end to avoid ambiguity: "A scales with B in the same way as C **does**." But can it actually be ambiguous (or even grammatically incorrect) without that 'does'? For example, can it be interpreted as "A scales with B in the same way as it scales with C"?

Comment: When I read your sentence for the first time, this is what came to my mind first: **A scales with B in the same way as C scales with B.**

Comment: @Reza2020, And that's what I mean by the sentence in this case.

Comment: What mountain are they scaling?

Answer (score 2):

This example from a paper from Dianne Otto at the [University of Melbourne_Law School](http://learnwhr.org/wp-content/uploads/Otto_Womens-Rights_2010.pdf)

> - *[G]endered violence does not affect men in the same way as women.*

shows a deletion (of 'it/gendered violence affects') similar to that in your second reading. It is obviously grammatically acceptable, and the reading corresponding to your first reading

- *[G]endered violence does not affect men in the same way as women do.*

is obviously not intended. However, it is only discountable from pragmatics, not from the actual structure involved. There is no ungrammaticality in these deleted forms, only an inherent ambiguity. It is often best to disambiguate (by not over-deleting), and certainly clarity is paramount, but easily interpretable sentences are often left inherently ambiguous to avoid prolixity.

Comment: Leave it to @EdwinAshworth to use a word *I* had to look up: **prolixity**. Thank you, sir. You have expanded my universe.